# RxAndroid: How can I extract all contacts from phonebook?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm trying to get all contacts from phonebook that have a number associated with them. I'm encountering 2 problems here,

**1. I'm unable to get all contacts.**
I'm getting all the numbers for a contact, but it's only giving me about 154 numbers, which stops at the name starting with letter M, and the last number is being cut off in half (only first 5 digits are being printed and the last 5 are nowhere to be found), whereas the list goes off till "z".

**2. Unable to get single contact**
There are some repeats in phonebook, and for that I want to get only the details that are distinct, but I'm unable to get a single contact and make sure it's distinct.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
    mbutton = v.findViewById(R.id.extractContact);

    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission is not granted
                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                } else {
                    // No explanation needed; request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
            } else {
                // Permission has already been granted
                Observer observer = new Observer() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Object o) {
                        Log.d("Observer_contact", (String) o);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("Observer_contact", "Completed");
                    }
                };

                io.reactivex.Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                        try {
                            emitter.onNext(loadContacts());
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            emitter.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .distinct()
                        .subscribeWith(observer);

            }
        }
    });



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}
```

The code below is supposed to extract contacts, but I'm unable to figure out how to get it to return single contact at a time, so right now I'm using a StringBuilder to return the entire record.

```
public String loadContacts() {
    StringBuilder mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor mCursor = mContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    if (mCursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "= ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\s","");
                    mBuilder.append(name).append(", ").append(phoneNumber).append("\n");
                }

                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    mCursor.close();

    return mBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: what's the problem regarding rxjava?

Comment: How can I get the observable to request single contacts from loadContacts()?

Comment: 1) Most likely all contacts are in your string, it is just being truncated by the logcat, 2) As you're using a content provider using any sql raw query info in the query is tricky - why not create a holder `Contact` class that overrides `equals` and `hashcode` (you decide what makes a contact unique) and emit each item - that way the `distinct` operator should work, also downstream you could always collect to a list in your RxChain.

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't understand. How am I supposed to do that? I'm sorry, I'm just very new to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using these code alterations:

**In loadContacts(){}**

```java
    if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
        mBuilder.append("\"").append(name).append("\"");
        Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "= ?",
                new String[]{id}, null);

        assert cursor != null;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                    .replaceAll("\\s", "");

            // if number is not existing in the list, then add number to the string
            if (!(mBuilder.toString().contains(phoneNumber))) {
                mBuilder.append(", ").append(phoneNumber);
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

**And while calling the onNext() method, make it run for everycontact:**

```java
try {
    for (count = 0; count < mCursor.getCount(); count++) {
        emitter.onNext(loadContacts(count));
    }
    emitter.onComplete();
}
```

This way, the observable emits details for every contact in the form of a string, and all the numbers in the string are unique. Also, make sure to close `mCursor` with `onComplete()`, such that the cursor is closed only when the entire phonebook has been extracted.